# How can I embed a datatable in a php drawn table?

Tags: javascript, php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

Here is the attached CSS, and I also tried using CDN for both styles and Scripts and still it is not showing filters from data table CSS.

```
<table style="border-color:cadetblue;" id="dt_basic" class="table table-striped table-hover m-0 rounded-pill display dataa">
            <tr class="nasiabg2 table-active text-white border-1 border-light">
              <!--<th class="text-white">Reference</th>-->
              <th class="text-white">Fund Name</th>
              <th class="text-white">NaSIA Classification</th>
              <th class="text-white">Initial Fees</th>
              <th class="text-white">Max Initial Fees</th>
              <th class="text-white">NAV</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody class="border-light"> <?php for ($j=0;$j<$fDaily->num_rows();$j++) {?> <tr>
                <td> <?php echo $fDaily->row($j)->fund;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $fDaily->row($j)->asset_class." - ".$fDaily->row($j)->style." - ".$fDaily->row($j)->region;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $fDaily->row($j)->init_fee;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $fDaily->row($j)->max_ann_fee;?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $fDaily->row($j)->nav;?> </td>
              </tr> <?php }?> </tbody>
          </table>
```

Here is my table with the below Javascript.

```
<script src="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

[image: My table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official Datatable documentation you should follow the following structure :

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
        <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Yep, can you confirm the answer please ?